# scroll down process trail line not working properly when screen size changes, especially for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a process trail line animation , on scroll down for showing steps (tutorial) for my website.

I am using the following JavaScript code to trigger the animation .

the problem is when screen size changes the pixel calculation goes wrong. and the animation works abnormally , especially for mobile. how can I make the animation responsive.

As shown in the image the line div joinning 2 and 3 does not join when screen size changes

[image]

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) 
       {
   
       var scroll1 = $(window).scrollTop();
       //document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = scroll1;
  if( scroll1>1000)
  {
  $('#step1 #span1').addClass('active');
  $('#bar1').addClass('bar');
  if(scroll1<=1123)
   {
    var x=scroll1-1000;
    //var bar= document.getElementsByClassName("barblue");
    //bar[0].style.height= x+"px";
    //$(".bar").height(x);
    document.getElementById('bar1').style.height= x+"px";
   }
  }
  else
  {
  $('#step1 #span1').removeClass('active');
  $('#bar1').removeClass('bar');
  }
  
  if( scroll1>1123)
  {
  $('#step2 #span2').addClass('active');
  $('#bar2').addClass('bar');
  if(scroll1<=1300)
   {
    var x2=scroll1-1123;
     //document.getElementById('scroll').innerHTML = x2;
    document.getElementById('bar2').style.height= x2+"px";
   }
  }
  else
  {
  $('#step2 #span2').removeClass('active');
  $('#bar2').removeClass('bar');
  }
  
  if( scroll1>1246)
  {
  $('#step3 #span3').addClass('active');
  }
  else
  {
  $('#step3 #span3').removeClass('active');
  }
  
}
);
```

```html
<div id="container" style="float:left;width:33%;">  


<div id="process-steps">
      <div id="step1" style="padding-left:120px;" class="scroll-no"><span id="span1" >1</span></div>
      
      <div style="padding-left:140px;"><div id="bar1" class=""></div></div>
      
      <div id="step2" style="padding-left:120px;" class="scroll-no"><span id="span2">2</span></div>
      
      <div style="padding-left:140px;"><div id="bar2" class=""></div></div>      
      
      <div id="step3" style="padding-left:120px;" class="scroll-no"><span id="span3">3</span></div>
     </div>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

I'm Not Sure

```
.timeline {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

    .timeline:before {
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        content: " ";
        width: 3px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -1.5px;
    }

    .timeline > li {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

        .timeline > li:before,
        .timeline > li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        .timeline > li:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .timeline > li:before,
        .timeline > li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: table;
        }

        .timeline > li:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        .timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
            width: 46%;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
        }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 26px;
                right: -15px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-top: 15px solid transparent;
                border-left: 15px solid #ccc;
                border-right: 0 solid #ccc;
                border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
                content: " ";
            }

            .timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
                position: absolute;
                top: 27px;
                right: -14px;
                display: inline-block;
                border-top: 14px solid transparent;
                border-left: 14px solid #fff;
                border-right: 0 solid #fff;
                border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
                content: " ";
            }

        .timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
            color: #fff;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 16px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -25px;
            background-color: #999999;
            z-index: 100;
            border-top-right-radius: 50%;
            border-top-left-radius: 50%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
        }

        .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
            float: right;
        }

            .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 15px;
                left: -15px;
                right: auto;
            }

            .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
                border-left-width: 0;
                border-right-width: 14px;
                left: -14px;
                right: auto;
            }

.timeline-badge.primary {
    background-color: #2e6da4 !important;
}

.timeline-badge.success {
    background-color: #3f903f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.warning {
    background-color: #f0ad4e !important;
}

.timeline-badge.danger {
    background-color: #d9534f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.info {
    background-color: #5bc0de !important;
}

.timeline-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: inherit;
}

.timeline-body > p,
.timeline-body > ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

    .timeline-body > p + p {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    ul.timeline:before {
        left: 40px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        width: calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
        left: 15px;
        margin-left: 0;
        top: 16px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        float: right;
    }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 15px;
            left: -15px;
            right: auto;
        }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 14px;
            left: -14px;
            right: auto;
        }
}
```

[**Refer this demo page**](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-responsive)